# At a loss for getting an EL7 machine back on the network after rebooting

Tags: linux-networking, centos7, rhel7

I have a CentOS 7 machine at my office that I can't for the life of me get connected to my network after rebooting it.  It was previously using a fully automatic configuration with DHCP and working fine.  Recently IT changed the DNS and DHCP servers on our network, but the machine was still fine for over a week after that.

The other day I rebooted it, and have not been able to access anything on the network at all since.  I've tried every configuration I can think of and every process of altering network configurations I can think of (nmtui, ifcfg scripts etc) but the end result is I can't ping a single thing on our network.  When using DHCP, "journalctl -xe" shows that it's broadcasting a DHCP request but never receives a response.  When I use a static IP, the logs make it look as if it's working, but I'm unable to ping anything, or reach the machine from elsewhere.  My thought is that the DHCP server was working off a whitelist, but IT claims that anything on the wired network should be able to get a lease, and that seems to be the case with other machines.

I'd greatly appreciate any hints as to what to try next.  Is there a simple way to reset all networking settings to default?  Many thanks.

Comment: okay show ip route, ip addr amd dhclient -vv

Comment: This sounds like a layer 1/2 problem.  Verify that your cabling is still good, try an 'ifconfig <ifnterface>" and see if you're receiving packets, check if any VLANs have changed, and if necessary get a tcpdump on the interface to see what traffic, if any, is being received.